# Error creating spam filter rules in email body in dovecot

Tags: spam, dovecot, sieve, spamassassin

I have been applying the following rule to mark as spam if the body contains any reference or coincidence with the following "earn free money":

```
`#if body :contains "earn free money" {
#  fileinto "Junk";
#  stop;
#}
#if anyof (
#    header :matches "Subject" "earn free money",
#    regex :matches ".*gana dinero*" "i" :content "text/plain"
#) {
#    fileinto "Junk";
#    stop;
#}
#if header :contains "Content-Type" "text/plain" {
#  if allof (header :contains "Subject" "earn free money",
#             anyof (header :matches "Content-Type" "*text/plain*",
#                    header :matches "Content-Type" "*text/html*"),
#             anyof (body :contains "earn free money",
#                    body :matches ".*earn free money*"))
#  {
#    fileinto "Junk";
#    stop;
#  }
#}
```

Note: It is commenting the rules due to the errors it generates.

I run the rules:

```
sievec /etc/dovecot/sieve/spamfilter.sieve
```

And I get the following error:

```
sievec(root): Debug: Effective uid=0, gid=0, home=/root
spamfilter: line 35: error: unknown test 'body' (only reported once at first occurrence).
spamfilter: error: validation failed.
sievec(root): Fatal: failed to compile sieve script '/etc/dovecot/sieve/spamfilter.sieve'
```

I am using the `Dovecot` 2.3.13 version and apparently the `body module` is no longer available and I also do the following `sieve_extprograms` I have executed the following code to search for information matching what is required but it does not find anything, additionally I have already checked folder by folder and nothing neither:

```
sudo find / -name "libdovecot_body_plugin.so"
```

In the following path I found a file called "Pigeonhole.Sieve.Plugins.Extprograms.txt": `dovecot-2.3.13\dovecot-2.3.13\doc\wiki` I leave the information here in case it is useful: https://jsfiddle.net/5wn2fray/

I have `Dovecot installed and configured to use` SpamAssassin`

If it is no longer available, there is another alternative to be able to filter spam using information sent about the content/body of the mail received.